# Storing PDFs in MS Access Database using Forms

Tags: ms-access

I need to store PDF files in an Access database on a shared drive using a form.  I figured out how to do this in tables (using the OLE Object field, then just drag-and-drop) but I would like to do this on a Form that has a Save button.  Clicking the save button would store the file (not just a link) in the database.  Any ideas on how to do this?

EDIT:
I am using Access 2003, and the DB will be stored on a share drive, so I'm not sure linking to the files will solve the problem.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you want to store the PDFs in OLE fields? You don't say what version of Access, but pre-2007, there was huge overhead for this. Unless there's some unmentioned requirement, it's better to store the files in the file system and just put the path/filename in a text field in your data table.

Comment: This database will be accessible from a share drive.  So, as I understand it, the filesystem will look different (based upon the drive the user has mapped our share to).  This is why we were not using linking.  If we can avoid this limitation, obviously I would want to use linking instead of storing the file outright.

Comment: This is an old thread, but I never say Matthew's response to my question. To it, I'd say: don't use mapped drives, but use UNC paths, which will always be the same unless the server name changes or the share mapping changes. If either of those things happened, drive mappings would be invalidated, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

We have several databases that contain 10's of thousands of documents (pdf, doc, jpg, ...), no problem at all. In Access, we use the following code to upload a binary object to a binary field:

```
Function LoadFileFromDisk(Bestand, Optional FileName As String = "")
  Dim imgByte() As Byte
  If FileName = "" Then FileName = strFileName
  Open FileName For Binary Lock Read As #1
  ReDim imgByte(1 To LOF(1))
  Get #1, , imgByte
  Close #1
  If Not IsEmpty(imgByte) Then Bestand.Value = imgByte
End Function
```

In this case, Bestand is the field that contains the binary data.
We use MS SQL Server as a backend, but the same should work on an Access backend.

Comment: @birger
Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried implementing this code, but being so new to VBA I cannot for the life of me figure out how to implement it.  Could you explain, for example, what the "#1" and LOF names mean?

Comment: A file is opened, and it is assigned a number (#1). imgByte is an array of bytes. The size of this array is set to the length of the file 1: LOF(1).
The GET function reads the file, and stores it into imgByte. At that point, imgByte is an array of bytes representing the image file.

The Bestand field value is then set to this array and voila: the file is stored in the field.

Comment: End please note: this is something else than storing an object in an OLE field, because theis method does not add the OLE wrappings to the file.

Comment: +1, very interesting. I suppose that doing that way you avoid a LOT of size and processing overhead, but lose some functionality (like preview in a form or in place edit)

Comment: The OLE overhead is not much. But in place edit is really broken in Access 2010 so I'm glad we don't use that anymore!

Answer (score 2):

If you used the same concept but upsized to SQL Server- storing PDFs inside of an Image datatype (or varbinary(max)) then you could SEARCH INSIDE THE PDFs using Full Text Search.

I show that Microsoft says you can do this for any file type where you can register an IFILTER product.. and I just was at the Adobe website the other day and say that their Acrobat IFILTER is indeed FREE.

Comment: Very interesting ! But I guess this would only work with objects stored as OLE, not as blob like @birger's answer ?

Comment: ole in Access is the same as blobs in SQL Server.. blobs are basically the same whether it's a IMAGE datatype or varbinary(max), etc

Comment: Thanks. Agreed for the storage, but when you store "as OLE", you put the doc (or even a part of a doc) in a kind of enveloppe, including information on the possible client(s), a format description, a preview, etc... So I was wondering if that OLE enveloppe is required for iFilter to do its job ?

Comment: I don't think so. I've definitely pushed DOC/DOCX into VarBinary(max) datatypes, and then I'm able to do FullText Search for keywords stored in the document, and it works like a charm.  

I frequently use a product called Access Data Projects in order to populate SQL Server with blobs.  Literally create a new form bound to a single SQL Server table, and this will automatically use the OleObject ActiveX control type which allows you to double-click on a WordDocument stored in SQL Server in order to launch words.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: [ACC2000: Reading, Storing, and Writing Binary Large Objects (BLOBs)](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B210486&x=12&y=9).

What they do: Read a file in chunks and add it to a blob using a VBA function.

Comment: I am really new (< 1 week) to Access and VBA, so this seems awful complicated to me.  I think it does what I want, but is there anything simpler out there?

Answer (score 0):

A field of OLE Object, by default would use a Bound Object Frame on the form. Right click on it and you can Insert an object. It comes complete with browsing for the file. Double-click on the field and the actual document will open.

I recommend going with David's advice and link. Unless you have a need to transfer a single file and want all the PDF's included. Size and performance will be an issue.

If security is an issue and the Access file is the only control you have (You are unable to set security on the folder containing all the linked files.), then you would have to embed.